# What is a sudo password?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am prompted for a `sudo` password.

Since I am a user at a very basic level of knowledge, I am very shaky in getting to the terminal and/or using the commands. When I am told to take the step "enter `sudo` command", before which I am prompted for the "`sudo` password", what do I do?

I've never set a `sudo` password. I see from other questions that there is a facility called `passwd`; surely that has to be entered at the terminal... I'll try it.

Comment: It's asking for your own password, with the assumption that you have 'sudo' privileges (ie. you can elevate your privileges and super-user-do)

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo` password is your normal user password by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: This should be a comment...

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider This looks OK as an answer to me.

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider No. Comments are **not** for answers. It's a short answer, but it answers the question.

Comment: This takes me no further forward. My copy of Ubuntu was downloaded from the internet: if I had been prompted for a password, I would have made a note of it. I remember no such prompt.

Comment: What do you mean with "downloaded from the internet"? This is the normal way...

Answer (score 0):

welcome to linux!

First, you have to add yourself as a sudo-er. You need to do this as root, so you will need the root password.

Log in as root and type the following command:

```
adduser yourusername sudo
```

The log back out and log in to the yourusername account like you normally would

You should now have sudo permissions. You can test this by running the following command:

```
sudo ls
```

or some other benign command. If it accepts your password and runs the command, you are a sudo-er. You could also go to the settings and look in the user information, or probably another six different ways.

Your sudo password is cached in that terminal session for a while. So the next time you type a sudo command, it won't prompt you for a password.

Be careful though, if you are working as sudo, you can do great damage if you don't know what you're doing. Linux assumes you know what you're doing, with sudo there are no guardrails, you have the same power as root.

Comment: Thanks, but we immediately meet a problem. How do I "log in as root". If I log in to my usual screen[desktop] and then try to get to terminal, will that do it? I notice "you can do great damage if you don't know what you're doing. Linux assumes you know what you're doing". I can state quite clearly I do not know what I am doing. I am a basic level user of the machine as word processor. I would prefer not to go to terminal and sudo, but software packages sometimes ask for sudo commands.

Answer (score 0):

`su` used to be an acronym for **Super User**, i.e. root but now it stands for **Substitute User**. Root is like the administrator on Windows. And this makes `sudo` an acronym of **Super User DO** or **Substitute User DO**. By default `su` or `sudo` refers to root account (unless specified) which is generally password protected. Root account is password protected in order to restrict apps/normal users to perform certain tasks which can effect the performance of system or cause security threats.

Now, the `sudo` password is the password you used at the time of installation. Also, whenever you enter password it is hidden, i.e. no character/bullets/stars will appear like in Windows.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful from the point of view of explanation. My copy of Ubuntu was downloaded from the internet: if I had been  prompted for a password, I would have made a note of it. I remember no such prompt.

Comment: @TonyB Are you using Ubunu in VMWare/virtualbox?

Comment: Thank you @Kulfy. I have no idea what VMWare/virtualbox means. We must assume I am not using it.